# memory leak in ldap_start_tls

Tags: c, ldap, openldap

I am writing a sample program to connect to LDAP Server using STARTTLS. I am able to connect and authenticate the user using STARTTLS but it is giving memory leak in the program.
Sample Program:

```
#define LDAP_DEPRECATED 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ldap.h>

#define BIND_DN "cn=xxxx,dc=xxxx,dc=com"
#define BIND_PW "xxxxx"
main() {
    LDAP *ld;
    int rc;
    int reqcert = LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND;
    int version = LDAP_VERSION3;
    int ret(0);

    if (ldap_initialize (&ld, "ldap://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com:389")) {
        perror("ldap_init"); /* no error here */
        return(1);
    }

    ldap_set_option (ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &version);
    ldap_set_option (ld, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, &reqcert);
    ldap_set_option (NULL, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, "/vagrant/workspace/ca_certs.pem");

    rc=ldap_start_tls_s(ld, NULL, NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "ldap_start_tls_s: %d\n", rc );
    if(rc != LDAP_SUCCESS){
        fprintf(stderr, "ldap_simple_bind_s: %s\n", ldap_err2string(rc) );
        ldap_unbind_ext(ld, NULL, NULL);
        return( 1 );
    }

    rc = ldap_bind_s(ld, BIND_DN, BIND_PW, LDAP_AUTH_SIMPLE);
    fprintf(stderr, "ldap_simple_bind_s: %d\n", rc );
    if( rc != LDAP_SUCCESS )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ldap_simple_bind_s: %s\n", ldap_err2string(rc) );
        return( 1 );
    }
    printf("Initial Authentication successful\n");
    ldap_unbind_ext(ld, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Command to compile:

> g++ -o sample_tls sample_tls.cpp -I./include -L./lib -lldap

Command to run:

> valgrind --leak-check=full --log-file=./leak_tls.log ./sample_tls

Memory leak:

```
27 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 30 of 72
==19231==    at 0x4A06A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==19231==    by 0x35E7E016EB: PL_strdup (in /lib64/libplc4.so)
==19231==    by 0x35F0E38CAB: ??? (in /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.10.3)
==19231==    by 0x35F0E35B37: ldap_int_tls_start (in /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.10.3)
==19231==    by 0x35F0E35C4D: ldap_start_tls_s (in /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.10.3)
==19231==    by 0x400ACE: main (in /vagrant/workspace/ldapsample/sample_tls)
```

It looks like it is not stopping the TLS connection after unbinding. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: The leak is probably in libldap. Unless you have a debug build and/or access to the source  code it will be difficult to track down.

Comment: I am using oepnldap(version - 2.4.35) library.

Comment: The leak is in your code. You need to do something about releasing the `LDAP *`. See the documentation. It isn't at all likely that such a widely used library has an elementary bug like this. @PaulFloyd.

Comment: I am calling ldap_unbind_ext at the end of the program. From doc: ldap_unbind_ext() call is used to unbind from the directory, terminate the current association, and free the resources contained in the ld structure. Once it is called, the connection to the LDAP server is closed, and the ld structure is invalid.